# What is the sum of the series given below?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What is the sum of the series $ \sum 1/m! $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $e^x = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i!}$. Now what is $e^1$?